# Expectation $E[e^{\lambda B_{T}}]$ where $T$ is a stopping time w.r.t. Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value, stopping-times

Consider a $1$-dimensional Brownian motion started from $0$. Compute $E[e^{\lambda  B_{T}}]$, where $\lambda>0$ and $T$ was the first time $t$ for which $B_t=1$.

If this were $E[e^{\lambda  {T}}]$, then I would know how to compute it. However, I am a bit confused with how one can compute this expectation with $B_T$ involved. I assume this should be quite straightforward; one just needs to find a suitable martingale and then apply the optional stopping theorem and dominated convergence. However, I am not seeing it.

Could I use that $e^{\lambda B_t-\lambda^2t/2}$ is a martingale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B_T$ is just the constant random variable $1$ so $Ee^{\lambda B_T}=e^{\lambda}$.

Comment: Wow, I definitely over complicated that! Thanks.